# How to setup home network with xp and 7?

Tags: internet, home-networking

Can I create a home network between two computers if the operating system is not the same. In this case windows xp and windows 7.
Because I tried to create a home network but I think they don't work out fine.
My main purpose is to share files between those 2 computers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about setting up a HomeGroup, then no.  But can you setup a classic workgroup which Windows 7 and XP can join.  This allows you to share files and printers.

- [Pretty straightforward howto.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/share-files-and-printers-between-windows-7-and-xp/)
- [If you encounter issues with Win7 not being able to see the workgroup](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpronetworking/thread/7c4ae439-f0f4-4f1e-a62d-81b1387d3d2b)